Delete button and Add Drink not working as expected
1.I've got a purchase history screen where you can see all the orders. There's a delete button for each order, but when I tap it... nothing happens. The order just sits there, mocking me.
2.I've also got this "Add Drink" screen where you're supposed to be able to pick a drink and its size. But when I tap on a drink, it's like the app is ignoring me. No selection, no nothing.
const handleDeleteOrder = useCallback((orderNumber) => {
  console.log('Delete button pressed for order:', orderNumber);
  Alert.alert(
    "Delete Order",
    "Are you sure you want to delete this order?",
    [
      { text: "Cancel", style: "cancel" },
      { 
        text: "OK", 
        onPress: () => {
          console.log('Deleting order:', orderNumber);
          setPurchaseHistory(prevHistory => {
            console.log('Previous history:', prevHistory);
            const updatedHistory = prevHistory.filter(order => order.orderNumber !== orderNumber);
            console.log('Updated history:', updatedHistory);
            return updatedHistory;
          });
        }
      }
    ]
  );
}, [setPurchaseHistory]);

const handleAddDrink = useCallback((item, size) => {
  if (!prices[item.category] || !prices[item.category][size]) {
    console.error(`Price not found for ${item.name} (${size})`);
    Alert.alert('Error', `Price not available for ${item.name} (${size})`);
    return;
  }

  setSelectedDrink(item);
  setSelectedDrinkSize(size);
}, [prices]);

// In the render function
<TouchableOpacity
  style={styles.deleteButton}
  onPress={() => handleDeleteOrder(purchase.orderNumber)}
>
  <Text style={styles.deleteButtonText}>Delete</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>

<TouchableOpacity
  key={size}
  style={[
    styles.sizeButton,
    selectedDrink === item && selectedDrinkSize === size && styles.selectedSizeButton
  ]}
  onPress={() => handleAddDrink(item, size)}
>
  <Text style={styles.sizeButtonText}>{size}</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>

I've verified that the handleDeleteOrder function in _layout.js is being called using console.log statements, but the state isn't updating as expected For the Add Drink functionality, I've checked that the handleAddDrink function is being called, but it's not updating the UI or preparing the drink for addition. I've made sure that the setPurchaseHistory function is being passed down to the PriceComponent correctly.

have u initialized purchase history For eg. const [purchaseHistory, setPurchaseHistory] = useState(initialPurchaseHistory);
and the selectedDrink and selectedDrink size ?
const [selectedDrink, setSelectedDrink] = useState(null);
const [selectedDrinkSize, setSelectedDrinkSize] = useState(null);
lemme know.. cuz I think we can crack this

Yep, I've got that covered! In my main file (_layout.js), I've set it up like this
javascriptCopyconst [purchaseHistory, setPurchaseHistory] = useState([]);
Now, for the selectedDrink and selectedDrinkSize I've got those in my PriceComponent:
javascriptCopyconst [selectedDrink, setSelectedDrink] = useState(null);
const [selectedDrinkSize, setSelectedDrinkSize] = useState(null);

is it possible for you to share both the codes entirely?

sure there the code [link]https://gist.github.com/kingnoob3605/53d4dcb7cf448d36cdfb681dd13f1563

Ok i got it now... u are calling the delete function from ur AlexaCoffeeApp but the function lies in the price component although you have passed it correctly.... but the reason why it's not working is because the state purchase history lies in your alexaCoffeeApp component

Oh I see the problem now The delete function is in PriceComponent but the purchaseHistory state is in alexacafe that's why it's not working should I move the handleDeleteOrder function to the alexacafe  and then pass it down to PriceComponent as a prop? Something like this
PriceComponent    // ... other props   onDeleteOrder={handleDeleteOrder}
Does that sound right? if I should try this or if you have a better idea.

Yes you can try doing that.. lemme know if that works
